# Alignment distorted when changing to Landscape Mode [Ionic]

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gridview, ionic-framework

I am designing a grid based image display in an Ionic Mobile App. 
The issue is to fix heights depending on the screen size of the images.
When in portrait mode, i want to have a max height and when in landscape mode i want to have a max height. How to achieve that.

Below are the details:
It is showing correctly in Portrait Mode(Below Image) 
[image: Portrait Mode]

but the height gets distorted(One card gets stacked onto another) when i switch it to Landscape Mode.(Below Picture)
[image: Landscape Mode]

Now, the original height of the cards is 107px. Now, when i increase the height to 157px, the Landscape mode looks fine.(Image Below)
[image: Landscape with 157px height]

But, the portrait mode suffers as the height of each image(fixed size image) increases thus putting a space between the rows(Image below)

[image: Portrait with height 157px]

```
HTML
 <ion-nav-view>
    <ion-content>
      <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <div class="col col-50 cards" ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url({{list.imageURL}})'} ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-nav-view>


CSS
.cards{
      position: relative;
      width: 96%;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 0 px;
      float: left;
      height: 107px; // This works in Portrait Mode          
       }
```

Comment: try `height: 50vh` , it will calculate 50% of viewport height

Comment: @aje Its working in Landscape, but the portrait mode still comes with huge gaps within rows of the grid( Like the last image shown in post). Since, it is a fixed size image

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the media query:

```
@media only screen
 and (min-device-width: 401px)
 and (max-device-width: 736px){

 .cards{
  height: 157px;
 }
}
}
.cards{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 107px;        
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Here i give you an idea on how to do this.

```
function doOnOrientationChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        // landscape
        // add class plus_height = +157px height of the card element
        angular.element(document.getElementById('card')).addClass('plus_height');
        break; 
      default:
        // portrait
        // add class remove_height = -157px height of the card element
        angular.element(document.getElementById('card')).removeClass('remove_height');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);
```

Comment: not working..as the screen already changes before doOnOrientationChange method gets called in app.js in run method. Where to put the event listener